Azure Data Factory to generate SinkDataSet with Dynamic file type such as Parquet or Avro or CSV
I started using Azure Data Factory recently. I could not find a way to dynamically map Data Sink format such as Parquet, CSV or Avro depending on a parameter value. Any suggestion to the solution to this will be appreciated.
{
    "name": "Parquet1",
    "properties": {
        "linkedServiceName": {
            "referenceName": "TargetDataLake",
            "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
        },
        "annotations": [],
        "type": "Parquet",
        "typeProperties": {
            "location": {
                "type": "AzureBlobFSLocation"
            },
            "compressionCodec": "snappy"
        },
        "schema": []
    }
}

I want to let the value of the type attribute to be dynamic.

You cannot change the definition of the dataset like that while running pipeline.
If you are only requirement is to copy all kind of files you create copy activity with source and target as binary dataset it works.
If you are performing different kind of activity based on the format, then use switch activity.
According to the format you switch to that pipeline.

Add the parameter value in Expression then for
Default case : Add your csv file activity.
Parquet case: Add your parquet file activity.
Avro case: Add your avro file activity.

Thank you Jayashankar.. Appreciate your response. The challenge I have is that I already have different customisations for datasets. Then for each customisation, I was using 3 definitions of data sinks for file format. Thats why I wanted to find out a more streamlined approach. Anyway, I will restructure my pipeline to see whether those customisations can be combined so that I will need to maintain only 3 sink datasets.

got the expected results? @Ted

Thank you. I combined my custom logics in the sinks and used a workaround same way as you suggested. Thank you for your help
